# Django programming error relation does not exist despite model being created

Tags: python, django

I renamed some of my models and tried to apply the migrations, but Django didn't detect that they were renamed. Therefore I deleted the content of manage.py, flushed the db and then ran manage.py makemigrations and manage.py migrate. Now I get the following error when I try to access one of my models via admin console or via any queries:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/restapi/appuser/
relation "restapi_appuser" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "restapi_appuser"
```

When I ran manage.py makemigrations the output included (truncated):

```
Migrations for 'restapi':
  restapi/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model AppUser
```

I tried to run python3 manage.py sqlmigrate restapi  0001_initial with the following output (truncated):

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model AppUser
--
CREATE TABLE "restapi_appuser" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "email" varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "password" varchar(50) NOT NULL, "join_date" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL);
```

It seems to me like the model should be in the database, but I am wondering why I am getting this error

edit:

here the output of manage.py migrate for completeness:

```
> python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, restapi, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: When you flushed the DB did you delete __all__ the tables including the migrations table?

Comment: i ran "manage.py flush" - does that delete all the tables?

Comment: It doesn't, you should probably drop and recreate the database to get a fresh one

Comment: You can try `python manage.py migrate restapi zero` to undo the first migration, then retry `python manage.py migrate`. If the zero migration fails because the table doesn't actually exist, try it with `--fake`.

Comment: dropping the database and recreating it, then rerunning makemigrations and migrate fixed the issue. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

`sqlmigrate` only shows you the SQL for a migration.

You'll need to run `migrate` for Django to actually apply pending migrations into your database after you've `makemigrations`ed.